# How to match the element of a double vector in google test in C++?

Tags: c++, unit-testing, precision, googletest

In Google test framework to assert two doubles are equal we can use:

```
ASSERT_DOUBLE_EQ(val1, val2);
```

instead of

```
ASSERT_EQ(val1, val2);
```

To avoid precision issues. To compare the elements of a vector, the Google mock frame work has a nice macro called `ElementsAre`, Here is an example:

```
std::vector<double> vec{0.1,0.2};
ASSERT_THAT(vec, ElementsAre(0.1, 0.2));
```

Is there way to use a matcher similar to `ASSERT_DOUBLE_EQ` to avoid precision related issues when using `ASSERT_THAT`?

Comment: to the close voter: how is this unclear in any way shape or form?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Google mock has a number of [floating point matchers](https://google.github.io/googletest/reference/matchers.html#FpMatchers) for double precision comparisons, including `DoubleEq` and `DoubleNear`. You can use them in an array matcher like this:

```
ASSERT_THAT(vec, ElementsAre(DoubleEq(0.1), DoubleEq(0.2)));
```